# Pass variable to XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, powershell, powershell-5.0

Windows 7, PowerShell 5

In Bruce Payette's book *"Windows Powershell In Action"* (2) on page 754 there is a WPF example called *"Building a file search tool"*.

I need to modify the `ComboBox` (originally a `TextBox`) in the XAML by passing in PowerShell variables `$pwd` and `[Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")` by using something
like:

```xml
<Label Width="100" >Path to Search</Label>
<ComboBox Name="Path" Width="324" Height="23" IsEditable="True">
    <ComboBoxItem >d:\files</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

```bsh
$path = $form.FindName("Path")
$path.DropDown = $pwd
```

Is there a way to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify variable to XAML definition, like this:

```
 <Label Width="100" >Path to Search</Label>
       <ComboBox Name="Path" Width="324" Height="23" IsEditable="True">
          <ComboBoxItem >d:\files</ComboBoxItem>
          <ComboBoxItem >$pwd</ComboBoxItem>
          <ComboBoxItem >$([Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments"))</ComboBoxItem>
       </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Many thanks; but this is not interpreted, ie it shows as the literal _$pwd_.